# How to open bootstrap modal inside a section and not at top of body?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i'm developing a lightbox gallery with bootstrap and modal. Everything is working fine except my modal open at top of my page and not inside section. How can i prevent this? My idea it's to open modal inside section(dreams-wrapper).

Here's my code:

```
<section role="dreams-wrapper">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- gallery thumbnails -->
        <div class="col-xl-2 dreams-thumb">
            <a title="Image 1" href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/thumbnail-1.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 dreams-thumb">
            <a title="Image 1" href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/thumbnail-2.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 dreams-thumb">
            <a title="Image 1" href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/thumbnail-3.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 dreams-thumb">
            <a title="Image 1" href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/thumbnail-4.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 dreams-thumb">
            <a title="Image 1" href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/thumbnail-5.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 dreams-thumb">
            <a title="Image 1" href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/thumbnail-6.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Heading</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dreams-thumb').click(function(){
      $('.modal-body').empty();
      $($(this).html()).appendTo('.modal-body');
      $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
  });
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

that would be an option

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dreams-thumb').click(function(){
      $('.modal-body').empty();
      $('.modal-body').html($(this).html());
      $('.modal-dialog').css('margin-top',$(this).closest('section').offset().top);
      $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
  });
});
```